# Как растянуть поля формы на всю ширину строки в Bootstrap 3?

Tags: html5, css3, bootstrap

У меня 2 задачи:

1. Растянуть поля формы (*Inline Form*) во всю ширину родительского элемента.
2. Адаптировать форму (сделать так, чтобы она становилась горизонтальной) для мобильных устройств. Стандартная форма так себя и ведет, но на всякий случай написал, если придется добавлять что-то через `@media`.

Дано:

1. Bootstrap 3 и стандартный код *Inline Form*.
2. Родительский элемент, куда вставлена эта форма.

```js
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

```css
.forma {
  padding-top: 50px;
  position: relative;
}
.around {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 30px 50px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.48);
  text-align: center;
}
.form-inline {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section class="forma">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="around">
        <form class="form-inline">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputName2" placeholder="Jane Doe">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="jane.doe@example.com">
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Send invitation</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Рекомендую использовать bootstrap так как вас просят а не как вам хочется...

```
<form>
    <div class="row inputs">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
            <label for="product_id"><b>Product:</b></label>
            <select id="product_id" name="product_id" class="form-control ">
                <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="-1">Select</option>
                ...
            </select>
            <span id="errmess" class="error_msg"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
            <label for="fio2"><b>Имя:</b></label>
            <input name="fio2" id="fio2" value="" placeholder="Имя" maxlength="50" class="form-control " type="text">
            <span id="errmess2" class="error_msg"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
            <input name="submit" id="submit" value="..." class="form-control submit_btn" type="submit">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас форма уже имеет правильную ширину, вам осталось добавить только:

```
.around input, .around button{
    width:100%;
}
```